# why is my laravel auth not being imported?

Tags: authentication, laravel

I use the following snippet in my Model function. Why does it not recognize Auth? This is the how my model looks like. I am following this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-web-apps-from-scratch-with-laravel-the-eloquent-orm--net-25631

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
```

class User extends Eloquent
   {

```
public static $timestamps = true;

protected $table = 'users';

public function user_profile()
{
    return $this->has_one('User_Profile');
}

public function photos()
{
    return $this->has_many('Photo');
}

public function viewed()
{
    return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('User', 'interactions', 'viewer_id', 'viewee_id');
}

public function videos()
{
    return $this->has_many('Video');
}


}
```

Comment: It's clear that you misunderstood something, but it's hard to tell what. Paste the model instead. And the error you get.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?